# react-rails View not being displayed properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I am using `react-rails` to use React.js on my Rails project.
Rails 4.2.8

This is what my `assets/javascripts/application.js` looks like

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap/modal
//= require react_ujs
//= require turbolinks
```

I am using HAMl for view and importing the Component like this :

`= react_component('HelloWorld', name: 'John', prerender: true)`

And when I do View PageSource I can see something like this :

```
    <div data-react-class="HelloWorld" data-react-props="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;John&quot;,
&quot;prerender&quot;:true}"></div>
```

But There is nothing on the View and I am seeing this error message on the Console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: HelloWorld is not defined
    at eval (eval at module.exports (react_ujs.self-eb4e9994228856e343ab49d1aed6c23046bf4308ea6d46395e5c39170ab3e56f.js?body=1:95), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at Object.module.exports [as getConstructor] (react_ujs.self-eb4e9994228856e343ab49d1aed6c23046bf4308ea6d46395e5c39170ab3e56f.js?body=1:95)
    at Object.mountComponents (react_ujs.self-eb4e9994228856e343ab49d1aed6c23046bf4308ea6d46395e5c39170ab3e56f.js?body=1:303)
    at HTMLDocument.ReactRailsUJS.handleMount (react_ujs.self-eb4e9994228856e343ab49d1aed6c23046bf4308ea6d46395e5c39170ab3e56f.js?body=1:350)
```

The component file `app/JavaScripts/components/HelloWorld.js`

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Greeting: {this.props.greeting}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

HelloWorld.propTypes = {
  greeting: PropTypes.string
};
export default HelloWorld
```

What am I doing wrong ? Is it because I don't have `//= require components` ? Even on that case I was getting an error.

Comment: Did you see the following issue? And, if  you change HelloWord.js name  with HelloWorld.js, maybe fix. https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/issues/702

Comment: @hamdi Yes, in my case all the file is `HelloWorld.js` and class is `HelloWorld` and I am adding react_component as `Hello World.` I had typo above and I fixed it.

Comment: Could you try after remove the `prerender: true` option?

Comment: I still get the same error. This is my first time using React on Rails. I have seen that other people have `app/assets/javascripts/component.js`. I don't have that. Do you think that might be an issue ?

Comment: I think not. I am using react on rails but with react-on-rails gem not react-rails gem. I think we are missing something little.

Answer (score 0):

Move `HelloWorld.js` from `app/JavaScripts/components` to `app/assets/javascripts/components` and see if that helps.